# $\nabla u+u \nabla V=u \nabla\left(\log u+V\right)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the book *[Entropy Methods for Diffusive Partial Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-34219-1)*,  §2.1, p. 20 , the steady state solution for

$$u_{t}=\operatorname{div}(\nabla u+u \nabla V) \quad in \quad \mathbb{R}^{d}, t>0, \quad u(0)=u_{0}$$

is derived by using
$$0= \nabla u_{\infty}+u_{\infty} \nabla V=u_{\infty}\nabla\left( \log u_{\infty}+V\right).$$

Can somebody explain the transformation after the second equal sign?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \log u_\infty(x)=\frac{1}{u_\infty(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} u_\infty(x)
$$
thus
$$
\nabla \log u_\infty(x)= \frac{1}{u_\infty(x)} \nabla u_\infty(x)
$$
and this implies
$$
u_\infty(x)\nabla(\log u_\infty(x) +V(x))= \nabla u_\infty(x) + u_\infty(x)\nabla V(x).
$$